# Requirejs, how can I deal with baseUrl

Tags: javascript, requirejs

I am using require.js just for loading `not third party javascripts modules`.
So the `baseUrl` will point to this directory.
Let's suppose I would like to load also an extLib dynamically,
which is located in a different directory.

How can I fix this without rewriting the current `baseUrl`?

```
baseUrl: "js"

define([
   "myLib1",
   "myLib2",
   "extLib" // <-- lib which is located in a different baseDir 
], function () {
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a paths config to set the path for extLib:
http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config